# How to create delegate for Result property getter in Task c#

Tags: c#, .net, task, task-parallel-library

I need to create a delegate for Result property of Task in c#( TResult getter_Result)
I am able to get getter method for property Result

```
Resultgetter = (TaskGenericType).GetProperty("Result").GetGetMethod();
```

But to add this to delegate , the following are my tries.
My tries :

```
  Delegate d = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(MyDelegate), Resultgetter, true);
```

The signature of Delegate is

```
public delegate object MyDelegate();
```

But the issue here is :
 I cannot have "`object`" as return for my delegate, as the signature has to match with Result property.
When I tried writing `TResult` as return for my delegate `(`public delegate TResult MyDelegate()`)` , I am getting error that TResult cannot resolve symbol.
How to create delegate for `getter_Result` for Task object.

what I am trying to do :
1.Getting getter method of Result for a Task object . And invoking that getter after one event is done.

So in that process . 1I am able to get getter for Result. But facing issue when I need to assign to delegate because of parameter mismatch. hence , I need to understand how to give return type for Result.

sample code

The problematic code line is

Delegate d = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(MyDelegate), Resultgetter, true);
it is going to catch there ,

the stack trace in catch is

```
System.ArgumentException: Cannot bind to the target method because its signature or security transparency is not compatible with that of the delegate type.
   at System.Delegate.CreateDelegate(Type type, MethodInfo method, Boolean throwOnBindFailure)
   at getProperties.Program.Main(String[] args) in Program.cs:line 126



using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public delegate Task<string> MyDelegate();


class Program
{


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task<int> task1 = Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(() => 1);
        int i = task1.Result;

        PropertyInfo[] vals = GetPublicProperties(task1.GetType());
        Type TaskGenericType = Type.GetType("System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1");
        MethodInfo Resultgetter;
        foreach (var x in vals)
        {
            if (x.ToString().Contains("Result"))
            {
                try
                {
                    Resultgetter = (TaskGenericType).GetProperty("Result").GetGetMethod();
                    ***Delegate d = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(MyDelegate), Resultgetter, true);***
                }

                catch (Exception e)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                    Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
                    throw;
                }

            }
            Console.WriteLine(x.ToString());
        }


    }


    static PropertyInfo[] GetPublicProperties(Type type)
    {
        if (type.IsInterface)
        {
            var propertyInfos = new List<PropertyInfo>();

            var considered = new List<Type>();
            var queue = new Queue<Type>();
            considered.Add(type);
            queue.Enqueue(type);
            while (queue.Count > 0)
            {
                var subType = queue.Dequeue();
                foreach (var subInterface in subType.GetInterfaces())
                {
                    if (considered.Contains(subInterface)) continue;

                    considered.Add(subInterface);
                    queue.Enqueue(subInterface);
                }

                var typeProperties = subType.GetProperties(
                    BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy
                    | BindingFlags.Public
                    | BindingFlags.Instance);

                var newPropertyInfos = typeProperties
                    .Where(x => !propertyInfos.Contains(x));

                propertyInfos.InsertRange(0, newPropertyInfos);
            }

            return propertyInfos.ToArray();
        }

        return type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy
            | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    }


}
```

sample How I am fetching "IsCompleted" property

```
 foreach (var x in vals)
            {
                if (x.ToString().Contains("IsCompleted"))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Resultgetter = TaskType.GetProperty("IsCompleted").GetGetMethod();
                      //  Delegate d = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(MyDelegate), Resultgetter, true);
                        Func<bool> testFunc = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<bool>), null, Resultgetter) as Func<bool>;

                        Console.WriteLine(10);
                    }

                     catch (Exception e)
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine(e);
                        Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
                        throw;
                    }

                }
                Console.WriteLine(x.ToString());
            }
```

Comment: You'd need to use `Type.MakeGenericType`, probably - but it's hard to tell exactly what you're doing with only snippets. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @JonSkeet : Provided explanation of what I am trying to do. Thanks

Comment: An explanation is not what I asked for - I asked for a [mcve]. When we can reproduce the problem, we can try to fix it.

Comment: @JonSkeet sure. Added sample code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Well currently you're trying to create a delegate with a return type of `Task<string>`, for the `Result` property of a `Task<int>` - the type of that `Result` property is just `int`, not `Task` of anything...

Comment: @JonSkeet : true . But here I know the return is int. But in generic case , how can I write a delegate to handle any such return type ? In msdn , I could see TResult as type . but when I tried to use TResult (like  public delegate TResult MyDelegate() ) , it is not even recognizing it :(

Comment: Well no, it wouldn't - because `TResult` is the type parameter of `Task<TResult>`. What would you do with such a delegate after creating it, if you didn't know the result type? (And bear in mind that the type of `Result` *isn't a task*.)

Comment: yes , but end of the day , any result type must have been derived from object class . So I can even use result.toString() (according to my business logic , all return values are objects for few random classes and all those are derived from Object)

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't explain why you're currently trying to build a `MyDelegate` (with a return value of `Task<string>`) from a property that returns an `int`... it's all very confusing. Do you really need a delegate at all? Couldn't you just fetch the property value with reflection?

Comment: @JonSkeet : this Task<string> is a mistake in my code. yes I have already done that with reflection using task.GetType().GetProperty("Result").GetValue(task, null); But I wanted to do it with delegates . hence trying this manner

Comment: *Why* do you want to use delegates though? You could potentially create an expression tree to include the conversion, then compile that... that would be simplest.

Comment: ok . Honestly , I am really not sure of expression-tree which I can learn and do. However , our existing code is using delegate to extract details like IsCompleted , Exception . So I want to follow same pattern even to fetch Result. For Exception , IsCompleted , the return types are constant . So no issues with those. But facing issue only with this Result

Comment: It's still pretty unclear to me, partly as your example code doesn't really make much sense. If you'd shown the way you're using delegates for the other properties, that would have helped. I've given an answer with two options, but it's entirely possible they won't help you...

Comment: @JonSkeet Added sample for IsCompleted.

Comment: That sample would not work. You're not even using x. It's pointless trying to help you if you only provide meaningless partial examples.

Comment: @JonSkeet I am using x in business logic . I cannot provide entire code due to company policies . and "x" I am using to compare the property .

Comment: But you haven't given an example which actually *does* fetch or use `IsCompleted`. I'm afraid if this is the clearest you can make the question, I can't help you any further.

Comment: @JonSkeet got it what u mean. That is my typo in the process of removing company policy code. I had to keep "IsCompleted" in GetProperty instead of "Result" . Typo. Hope my example is clear now.

Comment: Not really, because you're still creating a delegate which only gets the property from one specific, existing object - I'd expect a `Func<Task, bool>` in order to be useful. If you only want it for one object, then just call `Result` by reflection, as per the second part of my answer. If that isn't useful for you, you really need to give more information about *why* it's not useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via expression trees, but the way your sample code is set up makes it look like you want *just* a `Func<object>`, which means the task has to be already embedded in the expression tree. You can do that:

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task<int> task = Task.FromResult(1);

        var constantExpression = Expression.Constant(task, task.GetType());
        var propertyExpression = Expression.Property(constantExpression, "Result");
        var conversion = Expression.Convert(propertyExpression, typeof(object));
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(conversion);
        Func<object> compiled = lambda.Compile();

        Console.WriteLine(compiled());    
    }
}
```

If you want to do that, you might as well just call `Result` with reflection, and then build a delegate that returns that:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Compile-time type object to prove I'm not cheating...
        object task = Task.FromResult(1);

        var result = task.GetType().GetProperty("Result").GetValue(task);

        Func<object> d = () => result;
        Console.WriteLine(d()); // 1
    }
}
```

Neither of those looks particularly satisfactory to me, but hopefully you'll be able to get something useful out of them...